# Location service which allows creating and modifying data with REST API

Tags: python, rest, google-maps, here-api

I was wondering if there is a REST API where I can create/update/delete data. For example, what I would like to do is to create a pin on the map or save favorite place I find on the map through REST API.

Google Maps had this feature before but it is deprecated as from this post: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/maps-platform/announcing-deprecation-of-place-add

I was going through Google Maps API and can't see this option, also I've checked HERE maps API but it doesn't seem to provide this.

Is there any API where I could do this, basically send POST/PUT/DELETE requests to check how maps/location service works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out that ArcGIS provides what I need, I can add/update/delete points (or layers as they call it) on the map with REST API.

In case anyone else gets stuck with same problem, here is the article where it's nicely explained how to do this: https://developers.arcgis.com/labs/rest/add-edit-and-remove-features/

Answer (score 0):

You can use directly [Fleet Telematics Custom Locations](https://developer.here.com/documentation/custom-location/dev_guide/topics/request-constructing.html) REST api or you can use [HERE maps for JavaScript API](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/api_reference/H.service.extension.customLocation.Service.html) to communicate with this REST api.

Second option is to use [HERE studio](https://studio.here.com/) which is very easy to use.

Here is simple example how to upload point geometry (Marker) using HERE maps for JavaScript API:

```js
// assuming there is already H.Map (map) & H.service.Platform (platform) instance

const layerId = 'MY_LAYER';
const cleService = platform.getCustomLocationService();

// check if layer in fleet telematics custom location service exists.
// if yes, upload data. 
// If not create new layer, then upload data
cleService.getLayer(layerId, uploadData, createLayer);

/*
 * this method creates marker with random position and uploads it to the server
 */
function uploadData(table) {
  let row = table.addRow(),
      bearing = Math.random() * 360,
      distance = Math.random() * 3000,
      // marker with random position in radius 3km from map's center
      marker = new H.map.Marker(map.getCenter().walk(bearing, distance));

  // add marker to the map
  map.addObject(marker);

  row.setCell('NAME', 'Test name'); // optional
  row.setCell('WKT', marker.getGeometry()); // mandatory

  // push the marker's geometry to the fleet telematics custom location service
  cleService.appendRows([row], () => {console.log('O.K.')}, console.log);
}

/*
 * this method creates new layer in fleet telematics custom location service
 */
function createLayer() {
  // only WKT is mandatory column name
  let metaInfo = {
    layerId,
    columnNames: ['NAME', 'GEOMETRY_ID', 'WKT']
  };

  cleService.createLayer(metaInfo, uploadData, console.error);
}
```

Here is simple example how to show uploaded point geometries on the map using HERE maps for JavaScript API:

```js
// assuming there is already H.Map (map) & H.service.Platform (platform) instance

const layerId = 'MY_LAYER';
const cleService = platform.getCustomLocationService();

// Create a tile layer:
cleLayer = cleService.createTileLayer({layerId}, {
  resultType: H.service.extension.TileProvider.ResultType.MARKER
});

// Add the tile layer to the map
map.addLayer(cleLayer); // uploaded geometries start to show from zoom 12
```